# How to relink/delink image URLs to point to the full image?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I'm trying to change the URL's of a webpage on the fly using Greasemonkey.

The target page has links like:

```
<a name="217258323" href="http://foobar.net/photo/217258323/?pgid=&amp;gid=4933418&amp;page=0">
  <img style="border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px;background:#fff;"
    height="120" width="160" alt="Gallery pic 1 of 20 pics" border="0"
    src="http://i.foo.net/images/thumb/52/217/217258323.jpg">
</a>
```

I want to change them like:

```
<a name="217258323" href="http://i.foo.net/images/full/52/217/217258323.jpg">
  <img style="border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px;background:#fff;"
    height="120" width="160" alt="Gallery pic 1 of 20 pics" border="0"
    src="http://i.foo.net/images/thumb/52/217/217258323.jpg">
</a>
```

That is, I want replace the link `href` with the image `src` value -- but with `/full/` instead of `/thumb/`.

Any sample scripts or examples to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard image relink/delink problem, and you can probably find several premade userscripts for just about any site.

But don't try to do this with just regex, [that way lies madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/331508) (and broken scripts).

Here's how to relink your example using DOM methods:

```
var thumbImgs = document.querySelectorAll ("a > img[src*='/thumb/']");

for (var J = thumbImgs.length-1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var img     = thumbImgs[J];
    var lnkTarg = img.src.replace (/\/thumb\//, "/full/");
    var link    = img.parentNode;
    link.href   = lnkTarg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. However how could I make the links open in a new tab when clicked?

Comment: The smart way is just to middle-click the links.  Otherwise, add `link.target = "_blank";` just after the `link.href...` line in the code. `"_blank"` forces the link to open in a new tab (if you set your browser preferences normally).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
> var s = '<a name="217258323" href="http://foobar.net/photo/217258323/?pgid=&amp;gid=4933418&amp;page=0">\n   <img style="border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px;background:#fff;"\n     height="120" width="160" alt="Gallery pic 1 of 20 pics" border="0"\n     src="http://i.foo.net/images/thumb/52/217/217258323.jpg">\n </a>';
undefined
> var f = s.replace(/(href=")[^"]*([\s\S]*?)(src=")([^"]*)([\S\s]+?<\/a>)/g, '$1$4$2$3$4$5');
undefined
> var result = f.replace(/thumb(?=.*thumb)/, 'full');
undefined
> result
'<a name="217258323" href="http://i.foo.net/images/thumb/52/217/217258323.jpg">\n   <img style="border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px;background:#fff;"\n     height="120" width="160" alt="Gallery pic 1 of 20 pics" border="0"\n     src="http://i.foo.net/images/thumb/52/217/217258323.jpg">\n </a>'
```